# Stop NotebookEvaluate before the end of a notebook depending on test inside this notebook

Tags: functions, notebooks

CONTEXT:

Hello,

I have 2 notebooks, lets call them "Main.nb" and "FileProcessing.nb". In my "Main.nb" I have a Do loop where the iterating parameter goes over 300 .csv files which I want to process. I wrote the code for the processing into the "FileProcessing.nb".

However not every .csv file is in the right format - e.g. sometimes something is missing, hence the file is too short. I wrote tests into the "FileProcessing.nb", so as it is evaluating it can at several moments discover problems (= a test return False). In such case I want **to stop evaluating** the "FileProcessing.nb" and continue the Do loop in "Main.nb" with next value of the parameter.

QUESTION:

**Is there a way, how can I at several points in the "Fileprocessing.nb" decide if I want to proceed or to stop and continue in the Do loop in "Main.nb"?**

TOY PROBLEM:

I have the "Main.nb" and "FileProcessing.nb" in the same folder. The "Main.nb" contains

```
dir = SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]

Table[
 NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{dir, "FileProcessing.nb"}]],
 {filenumber, 4}
]
```

and the "FileProcessing.nb" contains

```
Print["Hello world! ", 100 + filenumber]

Return["Succesfully returned."]

If[
 filenumber < 3,
 Print["Test OK."],
 Print["Too big."]; Return["Stopped."]
 ]

Print["Hallo Welt! ", 100 + filenumber, "\n"]
```

There is `Return` on the second line, so rest of the code does not evaluate. It prints fourtimes "Hello world!" with number (101-104) in the "Main.nb" and returns table with fourtimes "Succesfully returned.".

As far, it behaves as I expected. It is "the proof" that `Return[]` works. **However, I want to return only if something "bad" happends (= a test returns False).** So if you remove the second line `Return["Succesfully returned."]`, then there is `Return` inside `If`. The idea is that if the test `filenumber < 3` is false, the rest of the notebook content should not be evaluated. But `Return` inside `If` means in fact something different. It does not return from the whole notebook, but only from the If statement and the rest of the code is always executed.

When I realised that, I tried to wrap `NotebookEvaluate` in `Catch` and instead of `Return` use `Throw`, but it does not work. It gives the following error

```
Throw::nocatch: Uncaught Throw[Stopped.] returned to top level.
```

Then I found in "NotebookEvaluate" documentation page that "The cells of the notebook are evaluated in a dialog subsession.", but I have not been able to use this information to my advantage...

PS: I use version 11.3 and at home (where I write this question) I have 12.1.

I would be very grateful for any help and guidance.

Comment: Is it important for you to have the code in FileProcessing.nb in a notbook? The preferred way to handle such a situation would be to turn the code in FileProcessing.nb into a function, put the definitions for that function into a package file "FileProcessing.m", load that package, call the function from it in the loop instead of `NotebookEvaluate`. That would make it much more straightforward to achieve what you want...

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good place to use `Throw` and `Catch`.  Try this FileProcessing.nb :

```
Print["Hello world! ", 100 + filenumber]

(*Return["Succesfully returned."]*)

Return[Catch[

  If[filenumber < 3,
    Print["Test OK."]; Throw["Success."],
    Print["Too big."]; Throw["Failed."]
   ];

  Print["Hallo Welt! ", 100 + filenumber, "\n"]

 ]]
```

The result in Main.nb is

```
Hello world! 101
Test OK.

Hello world! 102
Test OK.

Hello world! 103
Too big.

Hello world! 104
Too big.

{"Success.", "Success.", "Failed.", "Failed."}
```

Importantly, `Throw` stops evaluation and returns its argument to the nearest `Catch`, so you may not want to `Throw["Success"]` until after all of your `If` statements.

Comment: Your answer brings something I have not thought myself, thank you. However it does not solve completely my problem: The `If` statement should determine if the rest of the code should be evaluated or not.

Comment: The last line `Print["Hallo Welt! ", 100 + filenumber, "\n"]` is currently a placeholder for more code (but with your solution never evaluated) in which I may want to use similar `If` statement again.

Comment: @Ruze11  Yes, in this example the placeholder code is never executed.  But, I thought that was addressed in the last paragraph of the answer.  You would remove the `Throw["Success."]` from the first `If` and put it after all of the similar `If` statements.  Or, am I still missing something?  Perhaps I should move the `Throw["Success."]` to after the "Hallo Welt".  Would that be a more complete solution?

Comment: My problem is that everything has to be enclosed in `Return`. I don't want to have all code in one cell - the code is quite long and I still want to evaluate individual cells if I need. Basically I want to define "big function" that is not in one cell.